# Inheriting attributes in Java. New instance?

Tags: java, inheritance, logging, encapsulation

a pretty simple question about inheritance in java:

My abstract super class (only relevant content):

```
public abstract class Writer {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public Logger getLog() {
        return log;
    }
}
```

One of my sub classes:

```
public class ConcreteWriter extends Writer {

    public void write1(){
      getLog().error("msg1");
      getLog().info("msg2");
      getLog().warn("msg3");
      getLog().error("msg4");
    }
}
```

As you could see 'getLog()' is repeated each time I need to write a message, and I think that's not "elegant", and maybe it's not efficient as well.

I don't want to break the encapsulation principle of the OO programming, so I reject the use of the access modifier 'protected' in superclass (to use directly "log" variable).

What do you think? It's better to create a new instance of my log in the subclass? or something like this:

```
public class ConcreteWriter extends Writer {

    private final Logger log = getLog();

    public void write1(){
      log.error("msg1");
      log.info("msg2");
      log.warn("msg3");
      log.error("msg4");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having two separate fields which will always have the same value seems like a really bad idea to me. You don't logically have two different pieces of state, so why have two separate fields? Instead, just use a local variable in `write1` to avoid the multiple `getLog()` calls:

```
public void write1(){
  Logger log = getLog();
  log.error("msg1");
  log.info("msg2");
  log.warn("msg3");
  log.error("msg4");
}
```

For logging *specifically*, I would tend to have a private static final field per class, and not expose it anywhere else. It's unlikely that you need a different logger per instance, and logging should usually be seen as an implementation detail rather than part of the API, in my opinion.

So I'd have:

```
public class Writer {
    private static final Logger LOG = ...;

    // Use LOG when I need to
}

public class ExtendedWriter extends Writer {
    private static final Logger LOG = ...;

    // Use LOG when I need to
}
```

Comment: Personally I don't even see much use in adding the local variable. The code does not become much clearer (but that's obviously just an opinion). Sounds a little bit like premature optimization to me, as calling the getter shouldn't be really critical, especially as we are talking about Log4j log messages anyway ;-)

Making it a protected final variable might be ok, but personally I also prefer the getter method as you can more easily override a getter, if you need to (not that I see much chance for such a need there, honestly). For other objects it might make more sense.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz: I agree it's not important for optimization - but I'd probably avoid the repeated method call just for readability - I personally find this code cleaner than the first example in the question.

Comment: Thank you both. So, do you think it's better this option rather than use a log variable per subclass and do NOT inherit it from superclass? which is the best practice about this topic?

Comment: @John Skeet: I can not really offer any real argument against that, of course, since I think it's probably (also) a question of personal taste. But I could be wrong, of course. How do we decide if something is "more clear" than something else objectively?

Comment: @Emilio: That's not an option you presented, as far as I can see. Basically, is having the `log` variable important for the superclass? Are you *actually* talking about logging, or is this just one example? (For logging I'd be tempted to leave each class to do what it wanted, but then I wouldn't have a `getLog()` method...)

Comment: @Emilio: If you have the same code in all subclasses of `A`, then I would move that code to `A`, since it's redundant otherwise. Concerning loggers, I always tend to inherit them from the base class, if possible, but also that's probably a question of personal taste more than anything, since one line at the beginning of a class that clearly just defines a logger will not make your class much more or less readable.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes I'm talking about logging, tha's not just an example. When I said "do you think it's better this option rather than.." I was refering your option, no mine :)

Comment: @Emilio: But no-one had mentioned the option of "not inheriting from superclass". It's not really clear what you mean by that.

Comment: @JonSkeet I meant having "private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());" 1 time on each subclass, and nothing about log in superclass. My (second) question was if you think having a local variable that inherits its value from superclass on each sublass method, is better than this.